# How can I generate a link to the original tweet object using twitter search api?

Tags: twitter, oauth

I'm getting results back from the twitter `search/tweets` api. The problem is I'm trying to recreate a link back to the original tweet...which usually is in the form of:

`http://twitter.com/{user.screen_name}/status/{id}`

The problem is if something is a Retweet then the `user.screen_name` breaks the link (404) because a retweet points to the original tweet's id, not id of the tweet that is a retweet (if that makes sense)...so for retweets I need link to be `http://twitter.com/{retweeted_user.screen_name}/status/{id}`

I cannot see a flag in the response that tells me if an object is a retweet or not since there is no actual "retweet" object.

I'm surprised twitter doesn't actually a simple `metadata.source_url` or something easily accessible rather than me having to rebuild a link to twitter original tweet page.

Comment: Use `https://twitter.com/statuses/{id}` if you do not mind a redirect.

Comment: Ahh dang, thank you! I tried `/status/` and gave up. If yuu make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `https://twitter.com/statuses/{id}` works fine (thanks @pii_ke)

The problem was that twitter's search api returns both `.id` and `.id_str` and something I did not realize was that large numbers don't parse well in javascript.

You can read more about it here: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-ids-json-and-snowflake

...but the just of it is that you should always use the `.id_str` and keep these id numbers as strings.

`(90071992547409921).toString()` is parsed as `'90071992547409920'` <-- notice the missing 1 at the end has become a 0?

This was my problem in addition to not knowing about `http://twitter.com/statuses/<id_str>`

In my case I was using a koa app in node.js on the server side and that was querying twitter's API which somewhere tried to parse that original `.id` as a string and lost some bits...using `.id_str` everywhere fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `https://twitter.com/statuses/{id_str}` if you do not mind a redirect.

Comment: does not work for me: `823817721204719600` I get a 404 `https://twitter.com/statuses/823817721204719600` here is the working link: `https://twitter.com/image_folder/status/797396021722480640` I think becuase its a retweet the id I get back from twitter is invalid.

Comment: There seems to be some difference in ids: ` "id": 823823414267777000, "id_str": "823823414267777024",`  don't know what these two ids are different for. the docs say id_str is just a string version but its missing the 024 in .id

Comment: Ids should be strings as javascript has an issue with large numbers as ids (see twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-ids-json-and-snowflake)

Comment: Yes, two things could have gone wrong. 1. Tweet ids causing integer overflow. 2. Some confusion regarding which `screen_name` is author of which tweet `id`. I addressed only the latter.